# Fancybox Close Not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

For some reason I cannot get Fancybox to close using the close button they supplied. I have managed to get it to close using an  tag however a popup window appears from nowhere when its clicked?

Here is a link to the page in question:

http://events.usefulsocialmedia.com/customerservice/brochure2-thank-you.php

Here is what I am calling:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <link href="assets/css/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function($){
            $.fancybox.open([{
                content: $(".popup")
        }]); 
        });
        </script>
```

The close button I added is on the RHS at the bottom (called close).

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="$.fancybox.close();">Close</a>
```

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Cheers

Comment: What error you are getting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To close the fancybox you can add class attribute to your link as below:

```
<a href="#" class="closeLink">Close</a>
```

JS CODE:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $('.closeLink').on('click', function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
        $.fancybox.close();
    });
});
```

Comment: `live` is deprecated from 1.7+ [src](http://api.jquery.com/live/) use `on` instead

Comment: Cheers @Grevling and dh :) Works a charm

Comment: Anyone know why stopPropigation is required?  For me - the fancybox would not close fully unless I had stopPropigation.    It just kind of lightened up but never fully closed.

Answer (score 0):

Just try like this

```
<a href="javascript:$.fancybox.close();" >Close</a>
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: you are getting some error in your script, please check your console and then try.

Comment: without closing the `<script>` you are trying to add one more `<script>` here like this.

`<script>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="assets/js/libs/polyfills/DOMAssistantCompressed.js"></script>`

Comment: I've just given solution for OP's case.